# Angular JS and IE11

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using the Wc3 schools example of angular js, however; the given code doesn't work when I run it in IE11.  It does work for Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
<p>My first expression from WC3S Schools: {{6+13}}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works just fine in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5jo29t2v/

Comment: can you try `ng-app="myapp"`

Comment: @entre it isn't necessary for the expression to be successfully evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet explorer blocks `<script>` tags that reference external scripts (`http://ajax.googleapis.com/...`) when you open the file from disk (`file://`) by default.

You might get a warning that tells you something like *"Executing of scripts and ActiveX-Elements is limited for this page"*. (screenshot in german)

[image: screenshot in german]

Either host your example.html on a server and access it via `http://...` or enable active content in IE. I would recommend running it from a server, since IE has other limits on `file://` links (like denying AJAX requests).

Answer (score 1):

When viewing HTML pages from a local resource (disk) you should allow scripts to be run when using IE. There is a yellow "popup" at the bottom of the screen, "IE restricted this webpage...." with an "allow blocked content" button. When you press this button it works